# How to create global function in Jenkins shared library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a shared library for Jenkins and am running across a bit of an organizational issue.

I have a number of pipeline scripts in var, however I'm finding there are a number of repeating functions and the code is not very dry.

One solution for this has been to create helper functions inside var like var/log.groovy, var/formatter.groovy. This has worked fine and I've been calling these functions from within my pipeline scripts like var/myPipeline.groovy.

I would just like to organize my var folder a bit better and keep my helper functions inside var/utils/log.groovy for example.

The problem is I'm not sure how to access them from my pipeline scripts inside var when I put them inside a sub-directory.

How can I access them? Or is there a better way to organize my global functions?

Answer (score 2):

You can put them in src in a package structure that makes sense organizationally. Them import the right things in your var scripts.

in /src/com/yourco/Formatter.groovy

```
package com.yourco

class Formatter {
  def static String formatThis(String something) {
    "this is ${something}"
  }
}
```

In your var

```
import com.yourco.Formatter
..
..
..
   echo Formatter.formatThis('test')
```

Comment: That would be my preferred solution, however I keep running into issues when trying to set it up this way.

Adding a script in src/Formatter.groovy() with the contents:

    def test() {
        echo "Hello World"
    }

And calling this from vars/myPipeline.groovy results in the following error:

hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: testPipeline.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), main([Ljava.lang.String;), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: Calling this results in the same error:

hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: testPipeline.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), main([Ljava.lang.String;), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: It sounds like your var code has a problem.  This file should have a single method in it named 'call' that gets a single argument which is the closure passed to the method.  The body of the method should eventually be a pipeline (that has the globally shared library method call in it).  If possible post the var code...